# Access Watson intents in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, watson-conversation

I have Watson 2.7.0 speech-to-text, Assistant, text-to-speech service.

My workspace contains general intents to provide general voice responses; as well as 'action' intents, which execute actions in Unity.

I copied the code from Watson Cardboard vr example in my own script, but found I was unable to access the intents. It keeps giving me the error below. My script worked fine without the 'action' intents part. What am I missing?

```
Type `IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.Assistant.v1.MessageResponse' does not contain a definition for `intents' and no extension method `intents' of type `IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.Assistant.v1.MessageResponse' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Comment: Please add details: What script, which version of Watson Assistant API, what exactly are you doing, ...?

Comment: @data_henrik Added details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageResponse` and `Intents` are objects since they can have additional user defined properties. You can parse out the intent from the response in the callback

```
private void OnMessage(object response, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleAssistantV1.OnMessage()", "Response: {0}", customData["json"].ToString());

    //  Get intent
    object tempIntentsObj = null;
    (response as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("intents", out tempIntentsObj);

    //  First intent
    object tempIntentObj = (tempIntentsObj as List<object>)[0];
    object tempIntent = null;
    (tempIntentObj as Dictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue("intent", out tempIntent);
    string intent = tempIntent.ToString();

    Log.Debug("ExampleAssistantV1.OnMessage()", "intent: {0}", intent);
}
```

Comment: I was using this script to access intent, however it wasn't working in my case. https://github.com/IBM/vr-speech-sandbox-rift/blob/master/Creation%20Sandbox/Assets/Scripts/SpeechSandboxStreaming.cs